# Как получить из списка вложенных в список словарей список нужных словарей по условию

Tags: python

Нужно вывесть список словарей, в которых максимальная скорость авто больше заданной скорости. Использовать нужно только конструкцю return.

Вывести нужную информацию мне удалось, но вместе с тем выводятся пустые словари. В чем ошибка?

```
def powerful_cars(brand_cars: list, minimal_hp: int) -> list:
    return [[{k: v for k, v in x.items() if x["HP"] >= minimal_hp} for x in i] for i in brand_cars]
```

> > [[{}, {}, {'name': 'Ferrari_488', 'HP': 661}], [{'name': 'Lamborghini_Aventador', 'HP': 690}, {}]]

Comment: Видимо, у вас есть записи, не соответствующие условию, а словарь то в любом случае создаётся. Можно попробовать далее профильтровать получающиеся списки на не пустые элементы. `filter` можно использовать, или только словарные и списковые сокращения?

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так сделать. Наверное, можно короче, но пока не соображу:

```py
[[z for z in [{k: v for k, v in x.items() if x["HP"] >= minimal_hp} for x in i] if z] for i in brand_cars]
```

Comment: Оказывается можно было и короче сделать)

Comment: return [[car for car in cars if car["HP"] >= minimal_hp] for cars in brand_cars]

Comment: Спасибо за помошь!

Answer (score 0):

```
[z for i in brand_cars for z in i if z and z['HP'] >= 690]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]